# Free resource being processed for new Task in C#

Tags: c#, list, task

As question, I'm having 2 or more tasks (using `Task.Run` to create new Task every time) accessing same objects(mostly List) sequentially and what I want to do is the previous task will free the resources so that the later one can access. The operation to process my object is a long running one (accessing database) so that I don't want to use `Task.Wait()`. I tried to use `CancellationTokenResource` but it doesn't work for me as the task still runs and holds the object. Any suggestions on what I should to make that happen?

Answer (score 3):

First off `Task` cancellation is *cooperative*, which means that the processing task has to periodically check if a cancellation has been requested and terminate accordingly. Not doing this is likely why your attempt at using `CancellationToken` failed.

That said, it sounds like you are trying to solve a variation of (or maybe even exactly) the **producer-consumer** problem. If so, strongly consider using the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) class as it deals with all the edge cases and provides a really easy interface. Producers just call `Add`:

```
myBlockingCollection.Add(item);
```

And a consumption thread uses `GetConsumingEnumerable`:

```
foreach (var item in myBlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
}
```

When all producers are done, call `CompleteAdding` to let the consumption thread terminate.

Comment: @BradleyDoNET Thank you, I just read through BlockingCollection, it looks like the way to go. But for now, I'm using binding list for the entire application. Switching to BlockingCollection in the application (I want to keep it consistent) is too much time-consuming for me. I'll test this one and see the result later.